# jQuery get text as number

Tags: jquery, variables

**This code doesn't work:**

```
var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
var current = 600;
if (current > number){
     // do something
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="number">400</div>
```

Seems there is some problem with converting `text()` from text-like value to number.

**What is the solution?**

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Always use `parseInt` with a radix (base) as the second parameter, or you will get unexpected results:

```
var number = parseInt($(this).find('.number').text(), 10);
```

A popular variation however is to use `+` as a unitary operator. This will always convert with base 10 and never throw an error, just return <s>zero</s> `NaN` which can be tested with the function `isNaN()` if it's an invalid number:

```
var number = +($(this).find('.number').text());
```

Comment: `+` won't return zero for an invalid number, it will return `NaN`. IMO, this makes it more ideal than *parseInt()*, because *parseInt* will attempt to find a number at the start of a malformed string which can result in confusion (e.g. 1,000 becomes 1). `+str` is the same as writing `Number(str)`.

Comment: Something I ran into when using parseInt() is that when I got a NaN result, it would mess up calculations. I fixed this by using a bitwise operator. An example is:

`parseInt($(this).find('.number').text()||0)`

Comment: `.text()`  This is not a function. I used this and it says that ".text() is not a functions"

Comment: @ChamindaBandara Then you are probably doing something wrong, like not using it on a jQuery object. Create a new question describing your problem if you need help.

Comment: There is parseFloat() in case you want floats instead of ints. FYI

Answer (score 15):

`myInteger = parseInt(myString);`

It's a standard javascript function.

Answer (score 4):

Use the javascript parseInt method (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
var number = parseInt($(this).find('.number').text(), 10);
var current = 600;
if (current > number){
     // do something
}
```

Don't forget to specify the radix value of 10 which tells parseInt that it's in base 10.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone came here trying to do this with a decimal like me:

`myFloat = parseFloat(myString);`

If you just need an Int, that's well covered in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = parseInt($(this).find('.number').text());
var current = 600;
if (current > number)
{
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number = parseInt(number);
```

That should do the trick.